# How to correctly modify the ~/.bashrc file

Tags: bash, datascience-anaconda

I am a beginner using bash and hence only know basic commands in the terminal. Nothing deeper than that.

I have come across the following error programming in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
OSError: No command "reg_resample" found on host (...).
Please check that the corresponding package is installed."
```

The function `reg_sample` belongs to the package NiftyReg, which I have installed following this instructions: [official webpage](http://cmictig.cs.ucl.ac.uk/wiki/index.php/NiftyReg_install) for Linux.

The last instruction in the link, and the focus of my question, is:

"Update your ~/.profile or ~/.basrc file with the following lines:"

```bsh
export NIFTYREG_INSTALL=<niftyreg_install>
PATH=${PATH}:${NIFTYREG_INSTALL}/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${NIFTYREG_INSTALL}/lib
export PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

This is what I see if I open the `~/.bashrc` file:

```bsh
# >>> conda initialize >>>                                                             
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!                         
__conda_setup="$('/hepgpu3-data2/luismi98/anaconda/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /\
dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/hepgpu3-data2/luismi98/anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/hepgpu3-data2/luismi98/anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/hepgpu3-data2/luismi98/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

**My attempt**
So I just blindly pasted those lines below the `export PATH="/hep...`, leaving the else statement looking like:

```bsh
else
        export PATH="/hepgpu3-data2/luismi98/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

        export NIFTYREG_INSTALL="/hepgpu3-data2/luismi98/niftyreg_install/bin:$PATH"
        PATH=${PATH}:${NIFTYREG_INSTALL}/bin
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${NIFTYREG_INSTALL}/lib
        export PATH
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

where I have substituted `<niftyreg_install>` for `"/hepgpu3-data2/luismi98/niftyreg_install/bin:$PATH"` because that is the path where my `niftyreg_install` directory is, and I added `/bin:$PATH` at the end just to imitate the line that was already there.

**Problem**
After trying this, I tried running the code again and it spit out the same error.

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistakenly pasted the required information in the middle of an if/then/else statement. Delete those lines, and re-paste them at the end of the ~/.bashrc file.